# Ubuntu VM keeps rejecting incoming connections

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, iptables

Brand new Ubuntu 16.04 Server installed with just Postgres and OpenSSH servers in addition to the standard packages. After machine boots up, I can ssh and DB connect to the box. A few minutes later, I get "broken pipe" error and all services fail to connect.
Checked UFW is disabled and flushed all iptables rules, just to be sure.

Comment: Uninstalled UFW and iptables and still no change. I was able to open the web app and before I could complete the initial set-up wizard, I started getting the error: connection reset message again.

Comment: You will have to provide more information